# How to make an App Bar over an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, windows-8, appbar

I am playing around some windows 8 stuff and wonder how I can do the following in a windows 8 app.

1. Display a web page.
2. Implement a metro style app bar over the web page.

Here is my default.html:

```
<body role="application">
<div style="z-index:2;">
    <div id="standardAppBar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" disabled="false" aria-label="Command Bar"
        data-win-options="{position:'bottom',transient:true,autoHide:0,lightDismiss:true}" >
        <div class="win-right">
            <button onclick="sdkSample.displayStatus('Add button pressed')" class="win-command">
                <span class="win-commandicon win-large iconAdd"></span>
                <span class="win-label">Add to Menu_1</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="z-index:0;">
    <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ViewBox">
        <div>
            <!-- taking Apple.com as an example -->
            <iframe class="fullscreen" src="http://apple.com" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And here is my css for "fullscreen"

```
.fullscreen {
display:block;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:80%; /* leave 20% white space to right click to toggle App Bar */
}
```

Usually, the App bar can be toggled by right-click. 
But in the above code, right click doesn't work on the iFrame.
So I had to leave a 20% white space for me to click on to toggle the white space.
But I really want to make it to be fullscreen.
Anyone? Thank you very much.

Note: If you are on a touch device, the App Bar can actually be toggled by swiping your finger from the outside of the screen to inside of the screen. So that works just fine. But not for right-click. So this post is asking right click option. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by Microsoft fellows.. Reposting it here...

The idea is add a div over the iframe. Need to make sure the div has a transparent background and the div is "above" the iframe.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/45f947c5-ee79-4eed-8bb3-6352e89c8c05

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the 20% space you left at the bottom of the page. My bet is that the App Bar will show up. When you were swiping your finger at the bottom, you were touching the parent page so the App Bar shows up, but when you right click in the iframe the right click is not detected as an event on the parent page, so the App Bar does not show up.

In these scenarios, you will have to go with fragment navigation rather than the iframe navigation which you were using.

EDIT:
Assume the following **html** is in the body tag of default.html. 
**"contentHost"** div will be where you will load your pages(even the initial page)
The App Bar will exist on this page also.

```
<div id="contentHost">

</div>
<div id="trafficTipsAppBar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" data-win-options="{position:'bottom',transient:true,autoHide:0,lightDismiss:true}">
    <div class="win-right">
        <button class="win-command" id="settingsButton">
            <span style="background-image: url('images/smalllogo.png')" class="win-commandicon"></span>
            <span class="win-label">Settings</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The default.js will look like the following. 
You can use the **"navigated"** function as it is.
Also include this line **WinJS.Navigation.addEventListener('navigated', navigated);**
You will notice that on **WinJS.Application.onmainwindowactivated** we are navigating to **"main.html"** fragment, this is the initial load. You can create this by using "Add new item" > Fragment.
Also, when we click the "settings" button in the App Bar we will navigate to **"settings.html"** fragment

```
(function () {
'use strict';
// Uncomment the following line to enable first chance exceptions.
// Debug.enableFirstChanceException(true);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    WinJS.UI.processAll();
}, false);

WinJS.Application.onmainwindowactivated = function (e) {
    if (e.detail.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        WinJS.Navigation.navigate('main.html');

        var settingsButton = document.getElementById('settingsButton');
        settingsButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate('settings.html');
        });
    }
}

function navigated(e) {
    WinJS.UI.Fragments.clone(e.detail.location, e.detail.state)
        .then(function (frag) {
        var host = document.getElementById('contentHost');
        host.innerHTML = '';
        host.appendChild(frag);
        document.body.focus();

        WinJS.Application.queueEvent({
            type: 'fragmentappended',
            location: e.detail.location,
            fragment: host,
            state : e.detail.state
            });

    });
}

WinJS.Navigation.addEventListener('navigated', navigated);
WinJS.Application.start();
})();
```

Comment: Could you please explain it in more detail? I am new to this. Thank you very much. @sunil

Comment: Thank you very much for your update in this question, @sunil. But I still don't understand how your change will toggle the appbar. Are you suggesting that I should put a appbar outside of the body content so that it is always the same appbar for the whole application? If that is what you meant, then how the appbar can be toggled when you are on a page that only displays a full screen iframe?

Comment: The scenario I described above will only have one "App bar" for the whole "App". Can you please explain what you meant when you say "appbar can be toggled". Do you mean you want to hide the app bar when you go into another full screen iframe?

Comment: Yes. You can choose to hide and show the app bar depends on when you want it, by right-click or edge-swipe. So Thanks for your reply, but it is not really what this question is asking for.